# java oop: Two extended classes that need to be called regardless of type

Tags: java, oop, extends

I can't get my head around the following OOP problem in java:

I have two classes which extend some basic library classes.

```
class myMovie extends Movie
{
    int posi_x;
    int posi_y;
    ...

    myMovie(PApplet parent, String filename, int pposi_x, int pposi_y, float pangle, String player)
    {
      super(parent, filename);
      ...
    }

    int getFadeVal()
    {
        ...
    }

    void fadeOut(int pms)
    {
        ...
    }
    void fadeIn(int pms)
    {
        ...
    }

    void exit()
    {
      ...
    }
 }

class myImage extends PImage
{
    // Will get a somehow similar implementation
}
```

This works as intended. But now I have a "main loop" which draws all of these different objects and therefore i want to simply call the methods of these classes without asking of which type the object next in list is.

For me that means i need some type of head class which contains either a myMovie or a myImage. Something like:

```
class AnimationObject
{
    var child;
    ...
}
```

And then in the main loop just calling

```
AnimationObject[] ani_list;
foreach(AnimationObject ani in ani_list)
{
    ani.draw();
}
```

Of course the problem is that Java doesn't know something like "var". I Could use Object, but then i'd have to always cast the type of the object in the main loop.

Which is the correct approach to this problem? I can't really understand all those Interfaces, Abstract Classes etc. in contrast to my exact problem.
Which is the preferred and correct way to do this?
    }

Answer (score 5):

Use a interface for this:

```
public interface AnimationObject {
    void draw();
}

public class myImage extends PImage implements AnimationObject {
    [...]
}

public class myMovie extends Movie implements AnimationObject {
    [...]
}
```

And in your main loop use the interface:

```
AnimationObject[] ani_list;
foreach(AnimationObject ani : ani_list) {
    ani.draw();
}
```

Comment: great answer, perhaps add a note that the library likely already has an interface for this.

Comment: thats looks great, thanks, but how does this influence the use of my constructors? can i just create a mymovie object and put it in an animationobject list?

Comment: Yes there is no influence. You only have to implement the `draw()` method, respectively all methods defined in the interface.

Comment: Ok thank you. But i'm having a problem with attributes, a collegue mentioned that i don't need the interface but an abstract class. But as an abstract class i would need to extend again. thats not possible.

Comment: Therefore you would need to create a superclass for `PImage` and `Movie` which are classes of the library and hence cannot change them. Furthermore that would only make sense if the `draw` method for both classes would do the same.